# Find these linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector subspace of dimension $m$. Prove that there are $n-m$ linear functionals $f_1, \dots, f_{n - m} : \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $E = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \ f_1(x) = \dots = f_{n - m}(x) = 0\}$.
>
> Prove also that there is a linear surjective map $A: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n - m}$ such that $E = A^{-1}(0)$.

**My attempt of solution:**

If $x\in E$, see $x$ in the first $m$ coordinates of $\mathbb R^n$ (can we do this?). I know how to find linear functionals such that $f_1(x)=\ldots = f_{n-m}(x)=0$. It suffices to define $f_1,\ldots,f_{n-m}$ vanishing in the first $m$ elements of the basis. However, I don't know which it will be the values in the rest of the elements of the basis in $f_1,\ldots,f_{n-m}$.

Am I going the right way? I thought this approach a little bit informal because of the argument in the first line.

I need help to finish this proof.

Thanks.

Comment: Any basis of $E$ can be extended to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, do you recall a construction that builds a basis for the dual space $(\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$ from a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić yes, I do remember!